# Configuring hikari connection pool

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-sql-database, java-11, hikaricp

I have following settings for my database (I have multiple databases, so they are configured in `spring.datasource` hierarchy.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    db-write:
      url: jdbc:sqlserver://whatever.database.windows.net:1433;database=dbname;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
      username: 'myusername'
      password: 'mynotsosecretpassword'
      driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Then I am configuring my datasource here

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.datasources.dbwrite.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryDbWrite",
        transactionManagerRef= "transactionManagerDbWrite"
)
public class DataSourceConfigurationDbWrite {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db-write")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourcePropertiesDbWrite() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db-write.configuration")
    public DataSource dataSourceDbWrite() {
        return dataSourcePropertiesDbWrite().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryDbWrite")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryDbWrite(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSourceDbWrite())
                .packages("com.datasources.dbwrite.models")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerDbWrite(
            final @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryDbWrite") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryDbWrite) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(entityManagerFactoryDbWrite.getObject()));
    }
}
```

I am configuring my hikari datasource in `dataSourceDbWrite` method based on the properties i read in `dataSourcePropertiesDbWrite` method. I believe i need to configure properties in specific hierarchy so that `dataSourceDbWrite` method can easily detect which properties are needed for `hikari`. Is that correct?

What that hierarchy would be?

Moreover, how can and where can i find what properties i can configure for hikari? connection-timeout? connection pool size etc?

Comment: Common hikari properties in Spring: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.datasource.hikari

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Me personally prefer `application.yml` than code to configurate Hikari:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: {JDBC URL}
    username: {USERNAME}
    password: {PASSWORD}
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    hikari:
      minimum-idle: 5
      idle-timeout: 600000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      auto-commit: true
      pool-name: HikariCorePool
      max-lifetime: 1800000
      connection-timeout: 30000
      connection-test-query: select * from information_schema.tables limit 1
```

(BTW, that piece of configuration was originally writen by a colleague years ago. We didn't change it and just copy-and-paste into any new projects those years.)

If you want to check out all configurable fields, those `spring.datasource.hikari.*` keys in`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:{VERSION}/META-INF/spring/spring-configuration-metadata.json` may could help.

And javadoc in `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfigMXBean` could help too.

Comment: how can i verify if connection pools is created with correct properties?

Comment: @EmAe there are logs, you can add logs, you can add metrics, you can test  ...

Comment: Hi @EmAe you can confirm whether the connection pools is created with correct properties by checking spring boot actuator metrics like documented here https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hikari/

/actuator/metrics/hikaricp.connections
and other related endpoints are your friends in this case

Answer (score 1):

See example in [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources), the properties hierarchy are according to  `@ConfigurationProperties`'s value

> If we want to configure Hikari, we just need to add a @ConfigurationProperties to the data source definition:

> ```
> @Bean
> @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.todos.hikari")
> public DataSource todosDataSource() {
>      return todosDataSourceProperties()
>        .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
>        .build();
> }
> ```

> Then, we can insert the following lines into the application.properties file:

> ```
> spring.datasource.todos.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000 
> spring.datasource.todos.hikari.idleTimeout=600000 
> spring.datasource.todos.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
> ```

See relevant hikari's spring [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.datasource.hikari)

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-class-name
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout
spring.datasource.hikari.initialization-fail-timeout
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold
spring.datasource.hikari.login-timeout
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout
```

And explanation on each property in [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), for example

> **connectionTimeout**
> This property controls the maximum number of milliseconds that a client (that's you) will wait for a connection from the pool. If this time is exceeded without a connection becoming available, a SQLException will be thrown. Lowest acceptable connection timeout is 250 ms. Default: 30000 (30 seconds)

Notice that camelCase hikari properties (connectionTimeout) is shown as snake-case in spring (connection-timeout)

Comment: how can i verify if connection pools is created with correct properties?

Comment: You can enable debug mode `logging.level: com.zaxxer.hikari: DEBUG` in application.yaml and look at the logs